# Are there any asteroids between the Earth and the Moon which could also serve as a base

Tags: the-moon, artemis-program, near-earth-asteroid

I read about this tennis court sized asteroid
https://www.theguardian.com/science/2021/nov/11/near-earth-asteroid-is-a-fragment-from-the-moon-say-scientists

It appears to be between the Moon & Earth but in a weird orbit. Are there any asteroids which are easier to reach than the Moon? We could then maybe use it as a staging point for the Moon or Mars.

Comment: No asteroid could be between Earth and Moon for more than a very short time. Such a trajectory is impossible. The asteroid mentioned in the article is not between the Moon & Earth. Please read the article again very carefully.

Comment: @Uwe - Why is this impossible? This video talks about orbital resonances. [The Planets Are Weirdly In Sync](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qyn64b4LNJ0&feature=emb_logo). Can't such a resonance stabalize an asteroid between the Earth and Moon?

Comment: An asteroid in resonance between Earth and Moon is still between them only for a very short time. With resonance we get only a periodic repetition.

Comment: If there was anything 'between' the earth and the moon it would have to be orbiting us so by definition would be a moon not an asteroid  you could at least try and get your terminology right 

Answer (score 2):

This is actually one reason why we are considering landings on the Martian moons Phobos and Deimos. Using the chart below ([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Delta-Vs_for_inner_Solar_System.svg#mw-jump-to-license)), we find the $\Delta v$ budget for Deimos is 5.6 km/s, for Deimos 5.7, versus the Moon at 5.7 (all from low Earth orbit). The Martian moons would thus require nearly identical $\Delta v$ as our own.

[image]